# setTimeout() in componentDidMount() does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I am trying to change the state of a component every 5 seconds as below inside componentDidMount() hook

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class ToTest extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      test: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => { this.setState({ test: !this.state.test }) }, 5000);
  }

  renderDiv() {
    if(this.state.test) {
      return (<div>test is true</div>)
    }
    else {
      return (<div>test is false</div>)
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{ this.renderDiv() }</div>
    );
  }
}
```

But it executes only once. It changes from false to true once and then nothing.
What am I missing?

Comment: you need to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`, it will call the same function again and again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`componentDidMount()` is only executed once when the component mounts and you only schedule it once. You have to use `setInterval()` to schedule it periodically.

Also when you update the state based on the current state you should use a callback in `setState()` that takes the previous state as react may batch multiple calls to `setState()`.

And don't forget to cancel the timer in `componentWillUnmount()`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class ToTest extends Component {
    state = {
        test: false,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timer = setInterval(
            () => this.setState(prevState => ({ test: !prevState.test })),
            5000,
        );
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }

    // other methods ...
}
```

Comment: This workes but the problem I am facing that it reRender again and again because of setState and componentWillUnmount never call

Comment: @Sanaullah Then you call `setState` in the render method or in `componentDidUpdate` without a suitable condition. Likely every render you trigger a new update. `componentWillUnmount` is only called once when a component completely unmounts. It is not called after every re-render.

Comment: so how can I clearInterval

Comment: @Sanaullah I don't know what you are trying to do so I can't answer that. Ask a new question with the relevant code and comment with the link.

Answer (score 4):

Well `setTimeout` will only execute once, what you are looking for is `setInterval`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

> The setTimeout() method of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin (and
>   successor to window.setTimeout) sets a timer which executes a function
>   or specified piece of code **once after** the timer expires.

Compare with

> The setInterval() method of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin
>   **repeatedly** calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed
>   time delay between each call.

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments, you must use `setInterval`. the function `setTimeout` is called once. Make sure to clear the setInterval when the component unmounts. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount

The code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class ToTest extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      test: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => { this.setState({ test: !this.state.test }) }, 5000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer)
  }


  renderDiv() {
    if(this.state.test) {
      return (<div>test is true</div>)
    }
    else {
      return (<div>test is false</div>)
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{ this.renderDiv() }</div>
    );
  }
}
```