# Can't work setTimeout in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Try to build `setTimeout()` in React js. I setup this in `componentnDidMount()` but it works **only once.** Not working loop.

The code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(console.log("hello"), 1000);
  }
```

The warning show:

> [Violation] 'setInterval' handler took 99ms

How can I repeat this function?

Comment: Firstly, the first argument to `setTimeout` is a *function*, not a *function call*. So like `setTimeout(() => console.log("hello"), 1000);`. Secondly, `setTimeout` doesn't loop, you're thinking of `setInterval`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setTimeout() in componentDidMount() does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276487/settimeout-in-componentdidmount-does-not-work)

Comment: Answers are below, but remember to save the return value of the `setTimeout`/`setInterval` in order to call `clearTimeout`/`clearInterval` when the component unmounts so you don't have any accidental "access of ... unmounted..." errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setTimeout(*function*, *waitTime*)

when you pass a function to the `setTimeout` method, the method waits for a specified amount of time `waitTime`, and it calls the function `function`.
But passing in `console.log('hello')` only simply logs out `"hello"`, but does not return anything and thus does not actually pass a function or callable into the method.

Many ways to go around this:

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log("hello");},1000); //passes an actual function
setTimeout(()=>{console.log("hello");},1000); //lambda, passes an actual function
setTimeout(()=>console.log("hello"),1000); //same here
```

Also, if it was supposed to be repeated over intervals, then use `setInterval` (same arguments as `setTimeout`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval()`. Here is a good explanation: [setTimeout or setInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval)

**setTimeout()**

setTimeout() only execute **one time** when the time reached.

**setInterval()**

setInterval() is an interval based function and execute **repeatedly** when the interval is reached.

And examples for [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). Hope it helps.